# Disable thumbnailing on a per folder basis

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

I have a folder that contains 20 Gigabytes of precious gif images. When I open this folder my computer slows to a halt.

Does anybody know of a way to prevent Windows 8 from making thumbnails for only that folder. I know how to disable it globally. Maybe editing the mysterious thumbs.db file?

Comment: Your porn... erm, "precious images" will look better as `.png`s, FYI.

Comment: These are actually snapshots in a physics simulation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you go to View in the menu bar of Explorer... then Options and Change folder/search options. Click on the View tab, you can toggle "Display file icon on thumbnails." Or alternately, you can just view that folder in list or detail view.

[image]

[windows-8](/questions/tagged/windows-8) [thumbnails](/questions/tagged/thumbnails)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, Windows automatically remembers things on a per-folder basis. If you change a folder's view settings once, unless you make changes to the contents of the folder, it will stay the same. I can set Windows Explorer to use List View on a specific folder, or Tiles, or any other view, and when I exit and go back into Windows Explorer, and even if I reboot it will stay the same.

So, you really only have to endure the pain of loading all the tile thumbnails once, and you can then change it to another view and most likely never have to worry about it again.